# Editor does not contain main type

Tags: eclipse, scala

first of all, i like to say that i have read the other two questions regarding the same problem, and the solutions outlined in them did not help me. i tried cleaning, rebuilding, re-opening but it ddnt work out. I use eclipse for scala dev. This is the sample prog that i am trying to get an output from, its just casbah.

```
package com.examples.casbah

import com.novus.casbah.mongodb.MongoConnection

object newObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val mongoConn = MongoConnection()
    val mongoDB = mongoConn("casbah_test")

    val builder = MongoDBObject.newBuilder
    builder += "foo" -> "bar"
    builder += "x" -> "y"
    builder += ("pie" -> 3.14)
    builder += ("spam" -> "eggs", "mmm" -> "bacon")
    // You must explicitly cast the result to a DBObject
    // to receive it as such; you can also request it 'asDBObject'
    val newObj = builder.result.asDBObject

    Console.println(("A", "ProGGram"))
  }
}
```

I get the following error in the eclipse error log:

An unexpected exception was thrown

this is the [stack trace](http://pastebin.ca/1944928)

i read one comment about trying to run via clicking on the root of source project. But i only see Run as Java Applet and Run as Java Application. There is no option to run as Scala application. I have to run it using Alt+Shift+X S

TIA.

Comment: which version of the plug-in are you using and what version of Scala?

Comment: casbah plugin is 1.0.8.5 ie, the latest version from the casbah's site. umm, about scala, i have 2.7.3final installed (i get that from scalac -version). eclipse uses 2.8.0final, as shown under the package explorer.

Comment: also worth knowing, is that if i comment out the mongo related stuff, then i get the correct console output, without the editor cribbing about any missing methods.

Comment: i think the error is in the casbah plugin. no sooner do i comment out  the mongo parts, the errors stop popping in the logs and the program compiles w/o hitch. Also stopped seeing a failure in presentation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place for questions like this is the [Scala IDE user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user).